# Images built on the flutter do not output properly to the widget

Tags: flutter, image, dart, assets

i used CircleAvatar and input backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/image's name')

also i modified pubspec.yaml (I used command / to assets line)

but, I don't see the image in my emulator..

I don't know what caused it.

I attach an image for a detailed explanation.
[image]

[image]
[image]

The picture of the squirrel on the left is the image I want.

However, the widget shows a blue circle.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to put .jpeg after the name

Answer (score 0):

In Flutter, when you are trying to display an image, it's important to include the proper image file extension (e.g. .jpeg, .png, .gif, etc.) at the end of the file name. If the extension is missing, the image won't be displayed. To resolve this issue, simply add the correct extension to the end of the file name in the code that defines the image path. For example, if the original code reads

```
Image.asset("example_image")
```

change it to

```
Image.asset("example_image.jpeg")
```